# Reticulate - Running python chunks in Rmarkdown

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, knitr, reticulate

Maybe I'm missing something, but if the following code is the content of my Rmd file

````
```{r}
library(reticulate)
use_virtualenv("r-reticulate")
py_available(TRUE)
```
```{python}
a = 7
print(a)
```
```{r}
py$a
```
````

when I Knit the file, the output for the last chunk is 7 (as expected). On the other hand, clicking the run all button in Rstudio (or running chunks one by one), results on `NULL` for the last chunk.

Comparing with the [R notebook example](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/rstudio_ide.html) it seems like assigning something to `flights` in the python chunk should make `py$flights` available for R, but that doesn't seem the case.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to access from R a variable created in a Python chunk previously ran (not knit)? How to "export" to R a variable created within a python chunk?
2. What is a good reference to understand what happens when I click the run button in a python chunk of a Rmarkdown file?

**EDIT**: Ok so after seeing the first answers here, I did update both knitr and rmarkdown to the latest version, but still had the same problem.
I added `py_available(TRUE)` to my file to make sure it was initialized, still, last chunk results in `7` when knitted, but running chunks one-by-one results in

```
> py$a
Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'a'
```

The problem is: Assigning a value to `a` in the python chunk isn't doing anything to `py$a` in the R environment. Maybe this "shared" environment between R and python isn't how the package is supposed to work? Also, for some extra information

```
> py_config()
python:         /usr/bin/python
libpython:      /usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so
pythonhome:     /usr:/usr
version:        2.7.14 (default, Sep 23 2017, 22:06:14)  [GCC 7.2.0]
numpy:          /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.12.1

python versions found: 
 /usr/bin/python
 /usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: [This blog post from (today/yesterday)](https://blog.rstudio.com/2018/03/26/reticulate-r-interface-to-python/) by the `reticulate` authors may be useful

Comment: The docs you link to say that reticulate is in the RStudio daily builds, not sure if it's actually made it to released versions of RStudio. RStudio already included a way to run Python chunks by just using the default `python` interpreter, but no cross-communication with R, that might be what you're seeing.

Comment: does it wor for you by know?

Comment: Still doesn't work, just edited the post with the information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Rmarkdown / knitr:**

*Running the chunks:*

Running the chunks without knitting the document is not supported so far. See here: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1440 or [Reticulate not sharing state between R/Python cells or Python/Python cells in RMarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324289/reticulate-not-sharing-state-between-r-python-cells-or-python-python-cells-in-rm/49435461#49435461).

*Edit: Workaround by Freguglia:*

"Workaround is to turn python chunks into R chunks and just wrap the whole content in the py_run_string() function, so whatever you assign in that piece of code is accessible from R by py$variable_name."

*Knitting the document:*

One way is to upgrade `knitr` as suggested above, but you dont have to and you also dont need RStudio daily build.

If you have a version of knitr prior to 1.18, you can include:

```` ```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::knit_engines$set(python = reticulate::eng_python)
``` ````
, see here: https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/r_markdown.html#engine-setup.

**Python:**

If it doesnt work ensure the python connection is running outside of rmarmdown/knitr:
`py_run_string("x = 10"); py$x`.

In case that also doesnt work, you should check:
`py_available()` and `py_numpy_available()`.

If it returns `FALSE`: Try to initialize it with: `py_available(TRUE)`.

If that´s still a no - check your config:
`py_config()`

It will give you further hints on the problem:

Examples for me were: different bit versions of R and python (32 vs 64) or somehow i ran into trouble having installed both Python2.7 and seperately Anaconda.

Comment: `py_run_string("x = 10"); py$x` works fine. It seems like `py_run_string()` is able to modify `py` in the R environment, while just running a python is unable to modify anything.

Comment: to be clear: add the  `knitr::knit_engines$set(...)` snippet and knitting the document still doesnt work? (Running the chunks without knitting is not supported so far,...)

Comment: Knitting the document works perfectly. I thought there was a way of executing chunks individually and "export" the variables to the R environment. This is not possible so far as you stated, also found the same here https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1440.

Comment: I accepted this answer, but I also want to add that a workaround is to turn python chunks into R chunks and just wrap the whole content in the `py_run_string()` function, so whatever you assign in that piece of code is accessible from R by `py$variable_name`.

Comment: good point, i added it and quoted you... You could also add your workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324289/reticulate-not-sharing-state-between-r-python-cells-or-python-python-cells-in-rm/49435461#49435461

Answer (score 6):

This is fixed in current RStudio Desktop e.g. `1.2.1114`. But if you are like me stuck with RStudio Server Pro 1.1.456 a better workaround than using `py_run_string` might be to use `reticulate::repl_python()` which gives you a Python console within the R console and allows you to run your python chunks by copy pasting them into the console.

workaround:
[image: workaround]
working:
[image: working]

Comment: I tried running the same code from the question in the daily build. While something has certainly changed, running the python chunk throws an error now.

Comment: I just clarified that it is fixed in Desktop (windows). Which RStudio are you using exactly?

Answer (score 5):

You must use the Rstudio daily build ([source](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/rstudio_ide.html)) and upgrade `knitr`, `rmarkdown` to the latest version.

```
> packageVersion("rmarkdown")
[1] ‘1.9’
> packageVersion("knitr")
[1] ‘1.20’
```