# Can't declare a python function in Rstudio/Rmarkdown

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, rstudio, reticulate

I am trying to execute a python code in Rstudio (Rmarkdown) in a python chunk and I cannot declare a function while I am getting an error:

`IndentationError: unexpected indent (<string>, line 1)`

(I am not mixing tabs with spaces or so)

The following code doesn't work in Rstudio's python chunk but works perfectly fine in Python Spyder IDE.

```
import pandas as pd

cars = {'Brand': ['1HondaA','2ToyotaA','3FordA','4AudiA'],
        'Brand_2': ['1HondaA','2ToyotaA','3FordA','4AudiA']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand', 'Brand_2'])
df

def convert(brand_column):
  df[brand_column] = df[brand_column].str.replace('A', '')
  df[brand_column + "_number"] = df[brand_column].str.extract('(\d+)')


convert("Brand")
df
convert("Brand_2")
df
```

Screen:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are needing to specify where you python is located. I am on a mac so here is how I can to do it. Your indent error did not occur to me, so maybe double check your indents and spaces.

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(reticulate)
knitr::knit_engines$set(python = reticulate::eng_python)
use_python("/usr/local/bin/python3")
```

```{python}

import pandas as pd

cars = {'Brand': ['1HondaA','2ToyotaA','3FordA','4AudiA'],
        'Brand_2': ['1HondaA','2ToyotaA','3FordA','4AudiA']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand', 'Brand_2'])
df

def convert(brand_column):
  df[brand_column] = df[brand_column].str.replace('A', '')
  df[brand_column + "_number"] = df[brand_column].str.extract('(\d+)')


convert("Brand")
df
convert("Brand_2")
df
```
````

[image]

If you have windows, it might be similar to `"C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\python.exe")` or such

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I realized that, in fact, it works while you Knit the whole RMarkdown document at once. However, did you try to execute the code line by line (or chunk by chunk)? While doing so, the error still appears in my case (and yes, I checked for indents and spaces).

Comment: not really, but [a few people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503195/reticulate-running-python-chunks-in-rmarkdown) have work arounds and use reticulate functions in other situations.